# Custom URL link for linked in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am trying to open, [**`linkedin`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) app from my `ios app`. It is getting opened but with the user's home page. I want it to open with some profile. How can i send the profile id or name with custom url.

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSString *actionUrl = @"linkedin://#profile/52458178";
NSString *actionUrlWeb = @"http://www.linkedin.com/in/chetankedawat";

BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:actionUrl]];

if (canOpenURL){
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:actionUrl]];
} else {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:actionUrlWeb]];
}
```

Comment: Nops. Its not working. It is opening my home page only.