# Share using LinkedIn in iOS app

Tags: api, swift, linkedin-api, url-scheme

I am trying to share link on LinkedIn using swift. Below is my code:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=78a08cwgh3mdr5&redirect_uri=GooglePlusShare://&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile")

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

It moves to safari an shows

[image]

I had added the app's URL schemes in redirect uri. Please let me know where am I making the mistake or is there any other way to share content on LinkedIn. I don't want to use third party extension.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The URL string should starts with `"linkedin://"` as shown in this post:
[Custom URL link for linked in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970370/custom-url-link-for-linked-in-app)

```
var url = NSURL(string: "linkedin://#profile/78a08")

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

Comment: I am trying to do the OAuth for LinkedIn. It's not working. There is problem related to redirect URI. I had given URL schemes in redirect URI, but its not working.